# Error with Internationalization extension while compiling php 5.4.8

Tags: php, installation, php-extension, intl

I downloaded latest php version from php.net i.e. PHP 5.4.8

I configured it with following command

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql --enable-intl --with-libdir=lib64 --with-pear --with-mcrypt --with-mhash --enable-mbstring --with-iconv --with-icu-dir=/usr --with-gettext --with-curl --with-mysqli --with-freetype --with-gd --with-curlwrappers --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-png-dir=/usr
```

After this I run 'make' which start building / compiling PHP. After some time

It throws me error

```
ext/intl/.libs/php_intl.o: In function `zm_startup_intl':
php-5.4.8/ext/intl/php_intl.c:651: undefined reference to `spoofchecker_register_Spoofchecker_class'
php-5.4.8/ext/intl/php_intl.c:654: undefined reference to `spoofchecker_register_constants'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

Spent lots of hours finding solutions. I can't come out of any.
Does anyone know what this error exactly means? How to get rid of this error?

Comment: Try checking whether your ICU version is compatible.

Comment: I'm using CentOS 5.8 and I don't know how to check its version. Can you please tell me how to?

Comment: The SO FAQ allows for these questions "but if your question generally covers...software tools commonly used by programmers...then you’re in the right place to ask your question!". This includes questions about being able to build the dev tools to do your job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the ICU development libraries on your system:

```
yum install libicu-devel
```

You need to have [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) development libraries [installed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.requirements.php) and I think that error means you don't or it can't find the lib files.